# Selecting and updating a row while dealing with race conditions?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have a table of `elements` that can be `issued` to clients. These `elements` can only ever be given to a client once, and we have situations where many clients could be pulling elements all at the same time. We then need to return data associated with it (so there is an update, and then a select).

The current solution is that a random one is found/updated to be `issued=true` *and* sets its `id` as `LAST_INSERTED_ID`; then immediately afterwards it makes the select call to find `where('id = LAST_INSERTED_ID()')` which is unique per connection.

Since we're updating where `issued=false` to `issued=true and [last inserted]`, that one call is small enough to not encounter race condition issues.

But, all this is being done in SQL and feels very hackish. This does not seem like a rare enough problem that it has not been solved using a more Railsy solution. Wrapping a transaction might work to prevent double-issues, but then we'd need retry logic in the case the transaction failed.

What solution are we not thinking of?

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience here, and this is interesting to me. Are you finding and updating `issued=true` in one database query? How do you accomplish that?

Comment: Can you post your queries please

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use database-level locking to avoid race conditions.

One way to do this in MySQL is `SELECT FOR UPDATE` like this:

`SELECT * FROM elements WHERE issued=false LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`

In ActiveRecord (Rails), this is called [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html), and an implementation would look like this:

```
Element.transaction do
  element = Element.lock(true).where(issued: false).first
  element.issued = true
  # ... do other stuff to assign to a given client
  element.save!
end
```

If that got kicked off more than once at the same time, the 2nd call would be blocked until the first call finished, so by the time it executed, the first record would already be updated to issued=true and the 2nd call would return the next record instead of the same record.

You can read about `SELECT FOR UPDATE` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)